# The content of URL won't display

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

Goal:
Dipslay content of Test11 with url test1/test11

Problem:
The content don't display. What part of the code am I missing

Info:
*I'm new in React JS

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/redirect-to-default-route-reactjs-dxfeqf?file=index.js

Thank you!

---

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Test1 from "./Test1";
import Test2 from "./Test2";
import Test3 from "./Test3";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isUserAuthenticated: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test1">Test 1</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test2">Test 2</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/test3">Test 3</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <Switch>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => {
                  return this.state.isUserAuthenticated ? (
                    <Redirect to="/home" />
                  ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/test1" />
                  );
                }}
              />
              <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
              <Route exact path="/test2" component={Test2} />
              <Route exact path="/test3" component={Test3} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

Test1.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

export default Test1 => (
  <div>
    This is Test1 component
    <Link to="/test1/test11">Test 11</Link>
  </div>
);
```

---

test11.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default Test11 => <div>This is Test11 component</div>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a new route for your component.

**Add** this new route

```
<Route exact path="/test1/test11" component={Test11} />
```

**before**:

```
<Route exact path="/test1" component={Test1} />
```

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redirect-to-default-route-reactjs-cubyiq?file=index.js).